# Delayed Job object not properly deserialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

I'm having a hard time believing what I'm seeing, but it sure looks like DJ is failing to deserialize an object properly.  I look at the DJ record in mongo and I see in the YAML that the object has its `text` field set, but when the code runs, the `text` field is not set.  Here is some minimal repro code:

```
class Board
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :text, type: String

    def process_text_field
        if not self.text
            raise "Text field is blank"
        end
        # Text field gets processed
    end
end

# in a controller
def start_doing_something_slow
    board = Board.find(params[:id])
    board.text = "Text field is set"
    board.save!
    raise "Text disappeared!" unless board.text
    board.delay.process_text_field
    render json: {:result=>'ok'}
end
```

I invoke the controller method with the browser, and check the DJ record directly in mongo.  I see in the YAML that the `Board` object has the `text` field correctly set.  But when it executes in DJ, it raises the `Text field is blank` exception.

Somehow it's not deserializing the object properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this took me about a week to figure out, so I'm posting it here to help others who fall into this trap.  Turns out this is a [known bug](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/issues/23) in delayed_job_mongoid.  And it's had a simple fix listed right there in the bug report for 10 months.

The problem arises if you use the identity map in mongoid, which acts as an in-process caching layer to the database.  For normal web requests, the cache gets cleared between each request, so your controller methods don't use stale versions of the objects.  But delayed_job_mongoid doesn't clear the cache between jobs without this patch (which I just put together): https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/pull/38

The result is your delayed jobs are sometimes using old versions of the objects, depending on what ran before them, which creates truly bizarre, mysterious failures that are extremely difficult to track down until you understand what's happening.